# foreach loop in ASP.NET Core makes the card arranged vertically rather than horizontally

Tags: html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I was using foreach loop in ASP.NET Core to iterate data and according to the number of the data I would want to create cards for each of them using Bootstrap. It is working but the cards are vertically arranged and not horizontal. Here are the codes I've used:

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row padding">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                @foreach (var category in Model)
                {
                    //Pass a model one by one as the foreach loop does. Alternative the code in Categories.cshtml can be pasted here directly into the foreach loop as well.
                    <partial name="Categories" model=@category/>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Categories.cshtml

```
@model CategoryofTask

<div class="card">
    <div class="zoom-effect">
        <img class="card-img-top" src=@Model.CategoryImageURL alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">@Model.CategoryName</h5>
        <p class="card-text">@Model.CategoryDesc</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small>RM @Model.CategoryRate</small></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I know what it causing the cards to arrange as it is? Thanks!

Comment: the server code helps you render the HTML content, how it's rendered is determined by the HTML structure & CSS. So this looks like a client-side issue. To minimize it, you should play with just the generated HTML, put it in some fiddle, play with HTML & CSS to have the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [grid row](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) only has a single column that you share for each category model. If you want each category to appear in its own column, you will need to move the column into the loop:

```
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row padding">
            @foreach (var category in Model)
            {
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                    <partial name="Categories" model=@category />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use a [card deck](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks) instead of a grid row to make the cards appear more nicely:

```
<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="card-deck">
        @foreach (var category in Model)
        {
            <partial name="Categories" model=@category />
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Using "card-deck" look great

Answer (score 0):

Add  `<div class="card-deck">`  before For for-each loop and close after your CategoryofTask binding. Check the HTML Snippet

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
            <div class="card-deck">
               <div class="card" style="width:50px">
    <div class="zoom-effect">
        <img class="card-img-top" src='https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U' alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Test Title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Descrption</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small>Data</small></p>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="card" style="width:50px">
    <div class="zoom-effect">
        <img class="card-img-top" src='https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U' width="50" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Test Title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Descrption</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small>Data</small></p>
    </div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```